# Operations on date and time with milliseconds accuracy

Tags: c++, datetime

I need to take the current local time, including milliseconds, and pass it to some embedded device. This device has now idea about calendar time, but has its own timer with 1 ms accuracy. So, when this device receives the current timestamp, it opens log file and writes this timestamp to the beginning. From now, it writes different messages to the log, each one with number of milliseconds elapsed from this initial time. Finally, embedded device log file is uploaded to the host and should be parsed, with all relative time intervals converted back to full calendar time. The first part in the host program looks like this:

```
struct timestamp
{
    int year;    // 0-based 
    int month;   // [1-12]
    int day;     // [1-31]
    int hour;    // [0-23]
    int minute;  // [0-59]
    int sec;     // [0-59]
    int ms;      // [0-999]
};

timestamp time_point_to_timestamp(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> tp)
{
    auto seconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tp);
    auto fraction = tp - seconds;
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(fraction);
    time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    tm* ptm = localtime(&tt);

    timestamp t;
    t.year = ptm->tm_year + 1900;
    t.month = ptm->tm_mon + 1;
    t.day = ptm->tm_mday;
    t.hour = ptm->tm_hour;
    t.minute = ptm->tm_min;
    t.sec = ptm->tm_sec;
    t.ms = static_cast<int>(milliseconds.count());
    return t;
}

void start()
{
     timestamp ts = time_point_to_timestamp(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
     // send ts to embedded device
     // ...
}
```

Now, when I get the log from device back to the host, it looks like this:

```
2018 6 24 8 25 52 598     // start time ts
500 message 1             // ms elapsed from ts
2350 message 2            // ms elapsed from ts
...
```

I need to parse this file and convert every message, printing its full date and time. For example, 500 will be converted to:

```
2018 6 24 8 25 53 098
```

So, I need some way to convert `timestamp` to any C++ type, that allows to add time intervals to it (`time_point`, `duration`?), and print it in human readable form. My compiler supports C++14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
int64_t to_epoch_ms(time_point<system_clock> tp)
{
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Then pass the milliseconds since epoch to the device, where it can be logged as e.g. `1529819166927`.  Adding milliseconds is trivial and fast, whether you do it directly using the `int64_t` or by converting back to a `time_point`:

```
time_point<system_clock> from_epoch_ms(int64_t ms)
{
    return {milliseconds(ms)};
}

auto tp1 = from_epoch_ms(ms + 123);
auto tp1 = from_epoch_ms(ms) + milliseconds(456);
```

Comment: The problem in this approach is that system_clock is not monotonic. Consider the situation when "milliseconds since epoch" was sent to device. Then system clock was adjusted, and log file is parsed with this adjusted time.

Comment: I don't see how the epoch time is any different to the split-apart Y/M/D/H/M/S approach in terms of what happens if the host time is adjusted.  In fact I don't understand where the problem would be at all, because once the host sends its time to the device, it no longer matters what the host clock does.

Comment: The problem may be in the parsing stage, when log file is copied back to the host. Timestamp printed on the host now depends on the host clock. It must depend only from the timestamp in the beginning of the file. Actually, the file must be parsed correctly on any host in any time zone. I must admit this is a bit tricky, I would not ask a simple question here...

Comment: If the log begins with the epoch time, which is always in UTC irrespective of system clock time zone, I don't see a problem.  Simply read the epoch time, convert to `time_point`, add milliseconds offset, and display.  The only tricky bit would be if you want to display in a time zone which is neither UTC nor the host time zone, in which case you'd need a third-party library for TZ conversion.

Comment: epoch time from system_clock is not monotonic, exactly as system_clock itself. However, your answer helped me to solve this problem, `mktime` is the function I was looking for. Thanks.